# lay out common rafters with combination square

Tags: carpentry, roofing, measuring

I need to mark common rafters (plumb line and birdsmouth) to build a lean-to roof. I only have a combination square, a rusted try square and measuring tape. 
All explanations involve either a speed square or a framing square. 
Can it be done?

Comment: Sure it can, with a little trigonometry. What's the actual height of your rafter lumber?

Comment: Alternatively, lay a rafter board in position and trace it on the end of the wall or beam. That's more than accurate enough for framing.

Comment: What pitch are you going to make the roof, and what size lumber are you going to use for the rafters?

Comment: You know that building a lean-to roof is just a gateway to other, harder things, right? Get a framing square. Or if you think you'll be able to resist the siren song of more carpentry, just cut a large-ish triangle out of plywood that reproduces your rise on one side, run on the other, and has a right angle between the two.

Answer (score 1):

As  Aloysius Defenestrate commented I realized it can be done with any piece of flat wood that has a right angle and straight sides.

Pitch is a ratio between rise and run, it doesn't even matter in wich units you mark it. For example: 6:12 ( or 1:2 ). Mark 6 cm (or inches) on one side of the right angle, mark 12 on the other side. Now use that as a framing square, marking the plumb lines and bidsmouth the same way as you would with a real square.

Thanks